# Why am I getting <identifier> expected error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, keyword

```
class return{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            boolean t = true; 
            System.out.println(" this is before");
            if (t) return;
            System.out.println(" this is not going to be printed on the screen");
    }
}
```

Here is my code and my command line brings

> identifier expected error

Who can explain where the problem lies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` is a java keyword and you cannot use it as class name, change it to `Return` or some other meaningful name

Comment: @Hover `return;` in main is totally fine

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I was beginning to worry how you got your SO score for a simple programming problem! :p

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: well it's not for being super-observant, that's for sure!

Comment: I would suggest to say that Java is a case-sensitive language, so `return` (all in lowercase) is a reserved Java keyword, while `Return` is not.